# Kong ingress to externalName service appends external name path

Tags: kubernetes, kong

I configured Kong Ingress to route requests to an `externalName`, an S3 bucket at a particular path.

```
annotations:
    ....
    konghq.com/preserve-host: 'false'
    konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'
```

This works just fine when requests from a browser have no path (response doesn't have a redirect, but loads with status 200 with assets from bucket path). For example `https://my.example.com/` will load assets from my S3 bucket at `/my/example/` path.

However, if request from browser has a path `https://my.example.com/client/path`, the request does get routed to S3 bucket path correctly, BUT the response is a redirect (status 302) and the browser's path becomes  `https://my.example.com/my/example/` (the path from bucket shows in browser instead of the path user entered initially)

Why is the S3 bucket path get appended to the browser location path? Is there a way to fix that and keep the original path in browser?